# Regular expression starting with "http and ending with /"?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I need a regular expression for replace URL likes this:

```
http://www.domain.com/web/
```

I tried:

```
$pattern = '/\bhttp\S*\/"\b/';
```

BUT don't work.

I need a beginning and ending the string, its a JSON string with a

```
"ImgRemotePath":"http:\/\/localhost\/\/web\/images\/obj\/car.png"
```

or

```
"ImgRemotePath":"http:\/\/localhost\/\/web\/images\/"
```

And I need delete de last:

```
"ImgRemotePath":"http:\/\/localhost\/\/web\/images\/"
```

to

```
"ImgRemotePath":""
```

Comment: "BUT don't work." is not really a good problem description don't you say?

Comment: Please clarify: Should both URL types be replaced with empty string or only the ones that link to a directory?

Answer (score 1):

This should be somewhat what you're looking for:

```
<?php
// Subject data
$json = '"ImgRemotePath":"http://localhost/web/images/obj/car.png"';

// First procedure: Using regular expression to match and replace
/* Will match anything except '"' inside the JSON value
 * This limitation means that you should improve the regular expression, if
 * you wish to parse values that includes the '"' character, i.e. improve the
 * regular expression if this is needed, or use the alternative procedure     */
$result = preg_replace('/"ImgRemotePath":"[^"]*"/', '"ImgRemotePath":""', $json);

print $result;

/* Alternative procedure: Decoding, deleting value and encoding back to JSON */
// Convert JSON to associative array
$jsonArray = json_decode('{' . $json . '}', true);

// Set value to empty string
$jsonArray['ImgRemotePath'] = '';

// Cast/encode to JSON
$jsonString = json_encode($jsonArray);

// Remove '{' and '}'
$result = substr($jsonString, 1, strlen($jsonString) - 2);

print $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"http.*/"
```

try this pattern.
Basically, starts with "http, can have any chars and ends with /"

Comment: This will only match 'http: //localhost/web/images/obj/' if subject is 'http: //localhost/web/images/obj/car.png'